# PHP query - coalesce in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, coalesce

In mysql client the query with this condition work fine, but when put this query in php page, not work:

The variable are $_REQUEST:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE 1=1
AND idbook = '$idbook'
AND book_year between coalesce('$year',book_year ) and coalesce('$year',book_year )
```

If remove this line `AND book_year between coalesce('$year',book_year ) and coalesce('$year',book_year )` , the query work fine.

How to resolve it?

Comment: show also you  exact php code ..

Comment: What do you mean by 'not work'? Please explain what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is not working.

Comment: Not work, I mean the query not display the result without a error.

Comment: I try with condition <code>AND book_year between coalesce(null,book_year ) and coalesce(null,book_year )</code> and the query work fine. The parameter is the problem. Any idea to resolve it?